# Java Math.sin() doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, arrays, math, audio, trigonometry

Okay, my assignment is to produce an array values a sine wave with a custom frequency.
This is my sine function:

```
Math.sin(frequency*(j/samplesPerSecond)*Math.PI*2)
```

`j` is the array index and `samplesPerSecond` equals 44100.

Now for an array of 100,000 values it returns 0.0 for the first 33,000, 1.571509...E-14 for the next 33,000 and 3.143018...E-14 for the rest.

I've tried `System.out.println(Math.sin(Math.PI));` and it doesn't return 0 but it returns 1.224646...E-16

This is my first java assignment so I might be overlooking something really obvious here, but I'm really confused.

Comment: What is the type of j and samplesPerSecond?

Comment: Note that `1.2246467991473532E-16` is extremely close to `0`. `Math.sin(Math.PI))` is just limited by the precision of `double`.

Comment: j and samplesPerSecond are ints. A typecast helped me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing to this:

```
Math.sin(1.0 * frequency*(1.0 * j / samplesPerSecond) * Math.PI * 2)
```

See if it works better.

I suspect you have issue with integer division.

In Java 2/5 = 0, you know, while 1.0 * 2 / 5 
is what you would expect usually ( 0.4 ).

Comment: Yeah. Thanks a bunch. We used to use C, so this is something you want to get used to in Java.

Comment: @Marv Isn't it the same in C? ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are dealing with integer division. So if the numerator is less than denominator it will round to zero. Try converting/casting j or samplesPerSecond to float or double.

Answer (score 1):

> `j` is the array index and `samplesPerSecond` equals 44100.

As an array index, I assume `j` is of type `int`. This is your primary issue, as you're performing integer division, which truncates the result to a  whole number. Either cast `j` to a `double`, or multiply it by a double before dividing:

```
((double)j / samplesPerSecond)
(1.0 * j / samplesPerSecond)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried System.out.println(Math.sin(Math.PI)); and it doesn't return 0 but it returns 1.224646...E-16

It has been already stated that this has to do with the finite precision of double.
I use something like this in those cases:

```
 double result = Math.sin(2*Math.PI);
 for(double d=-1;d<=1;d=d+0.05){
        if(Math.abs(i-result) <1E-10){
            result = d;
        }
    }
 System.out.println(result); //prints 0
```